# Tensordot equivalent of einsum 'ij, ijk -> ik'

Tags: numpy, tensor, eigen3, numpy-einsum

I am not using numpy but Eigen::Tensor C++ API, which only has contraction operations, this is just to enable me think through implementation from python.

So 'ij, ijk -> ik' is basically like doing a for loop for each of the first dimensions.

```
a = np.random.uniform(size=[10, 4])
b = np.random.uniform(size=[10, 4, 4])
vec = []
for i in range(10):
  vec.append(a[i].dot(b[i]))
print(np.stack(vec, axis=0))
## or with einsum
print(np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', a, b))
```

This can not seem to be done easily with tensordot. Any suggestions?

Comment: What `tensordot` are you asking about?   The `numpy` can't do this.  `np.matmul` can.

Comment: I am asking for numpy. Hmm I see, it can be done with np.matmul by expand dim of a. But what I really want to solve is using Eigen::tensor library for such operations. There seems to be no such equivalence there.

Comment: `np.tensordot` just reshapes and transposes the arguments so it can use `np.dot`.  It does  not do any sort of 'batching'.  That's why `matmul` was added.  So despite the name, I wouldn't expect an equivalent in a C++ library.  But in C++ it shouldn't be expensive to loop over the 'batch' dimension.  It doesn't have the distinction between slow interpreted user loops, and fast compiled ones.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate on why it won't be expensive for c++ to do such a look along batch dimension? In may case, I could have hundred or thousand in the for loop.

Comment: In c++ all code is compiled whether you write it or you use a library.

Comment: but why would that make this problem fast tho? Isn't that still serial? In the case of np.matmul, I assume we can get some parallelism throu batching. Do you mean we don't need batching in this case but still get good performance in c++?

Comment: What is the real reason for doing this? Calling a BLAS routine repeatedly with such a small (vector,matrix) multiplication is actually the only thing which would be a real (performance critical) mistake. -> The calling overhead is far too high. The best thing would be to completely unroll the vector,matrix multiplication, but simple loops will also do there job.